# How to register for value change events on <input type=date> on iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, html

I am trying to create an HTML5 input date component so that I can take advantage of the native iOS date/time picker and I am using jquery.  I have the following code to generate the component:

```
  var $inputDate = $("<input></input>");
  $inputDate.attr("type", "date");
  $inputDate.attr("value", "2004-05-03");
  $inputDate.change(function(event)
  {
    console.log("value changed");
  });
```

The code is running inside a webkit component in a native app.  The input control appears fine and I can change the value using the picker.  However, the change function is not triggered when I change the value and dismiss the picker.  When I run this in a web page in Chrome, things work as expected.  How do I make this work on iOS?

Comment: Found other users complaining the change event wasn't triggered, they were suggested to use something like the following kit instead: http://cubiq.org/spinning-wheel-on-webkit-for-iphone-ipod-touch

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but using that kit doesn't give locale support which our product requires.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The onblur function is invoked when the date/time picker is dismissed.  So this does work:

```
var $inputDate = $("<input></input>");
$inputDate.attr("type", "date");
$inputDate.attr("value", "2004-05-03");
$inputDate.blur(function(event)
{
  console.log("value changed");
});
```

In newer versions of Chrome (and Chrome on Android):

- the onchange event is invoked when the date is chosen
- the onblur event is not invoked when the dropdown is dismissed, only once the control loses keyboard focus

Here is an example showing which event is generated using plain JavaScript: http://jsbin.com/iximuy/4

Comment: Man I was tearing my hair out over this one, thanks for saving me!