# JQ change won't fire

Tags: jquery, html

I have an HTML page, packed with JQ and a few scripts. 
I have to show some dates when the page loads, something like this:

1. Todays date
2. Todays date + 18 weeks
3. Todays date + 90 weeks
4. Todays date + 1 week

I have no problem doing this on the load.

This is the HTML markup:

```
<ul>
<li>
   today
</li> 
<li>
    <input type="date" id="dt0weeks">
</li>
<li>
   transfer: today + 18 weeks
</li> 
<li>
    <input type="date" id="dt18weeks">
</li>

<li>
   end date: today + 90 weeks
</li> 
<li>
    <input type="date" id="dt90weeks">
</li>

<li>
   week: today + 1 week
</li> 
<li>
    <input type="date" id="dt1weeks">
</li>
```

And this is the function that I execute `on ready`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var now = new Date();

now = new Date();
now.addWeeks(0);
$("#dt0weeks")[0].valueAsDate = now;    

now = new Date();
now.addWeeks(18);
$("#dt18weeks")[0].valueAsDate = now;

now = new Date();
now.addWeeks(90);
$("#dt90weeks")[0].valueAsDate = now;

now = new Date();
now.addWeeks(1);
$("#dt1weeks")[0].valueAsDate = now;

 });
```

However I want to be able to change the values of the dt18weeks, dt90weeks, dt1weeks now, by simply clicking on the 1st field and choosing another date, so in a function I'll sum the 18, 90, 1 weeks on the date I just picked.

However, not even this simple code will fire.

```
$( "#dt0weeks" )
.change(function () {
alert('i clicked on you');   
})
```

That's at the top inside of my `<script>` tag, no alert will show up.

Comment: Before anyone says it, the JS onchange Event DOES fire, just wanted to know why JQ doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your description, your jQuery code should be in a document.ready handler within the `<script>` tag in the head. Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#dt0weeks").change(function () {
            alert('I changed on you');   
        });
    });
</script>
```

Also note that the `change` event doesn't fire on an input until both the value has been changed *and* the user moves focus away from the input element.

Comment: This works, thank you. But let's say I want to change the last 3 dates, dinamically, in function of #dt0weeks, which is a date that the user can pick. I try to do it on the onchange event, as you said but I get Failed to set the 'valueAsDate' property on 'HTMLInputElement' error, I have no idea why.

Comment: `valueAsDate` isn't a property of an HTMLInputElement. If you're using a plugin, you need to call the property on the instance of the plugin for that element. If you're still having issues, it's probably best to ask a separate question about that problem.

Comment: Yeah, I just did here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31851488/failed-to-set-the-valueasdate-property-on-htmlinputelement I'm not sure however how to call the property on the instance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( "#dt0weeks" ).change(function () {
    var now = new Date();

    now = new Date();
    now.addWeeks(0);
    $("#dt0weeks")[0].valueAsDate = now;    

    now = new Date();
    now.addWeeks(18);
    $("#dt18weeks")[0].valueAsDate = now;

    now = new Date();
    now.addWeeks(90);
    $("#dt90weeks")[0].valueAsDate = now;

    now = new Date();
    now.addWeeks(1);
    $("#dt1weeks")[0].valueAsDate = now;
  }).change();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use blur instead of change:

```
$( "#dt0weeks" )
.blur(function () {
    alert('i clicked on you');   
})
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9831787/2633917

Answer (score 1):

When i first loaded up your code in JSFiddle I was getting an error complaining that addWeeks didn't exist which was meaning the change event wasn't attaching. However after fixing that the change event fired for me fine. Is it possible that you are getting the same problem?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var now = new Date();

    now = new Date();
    $("#dt0weeks")[0].valueAsDate = now;    

    now = new Date();
    now.setDate(now.getDate() + 126);
    $("#dt18weeks")[0].valueAsDate = now;

    now = new Date();
    now.setDate(now.getDate() + 630);
    $("#dt90weeks")[0].valueAsDate = now;

    now = new Date();
    now.setDate(now.getDate() + 7);
    $("#dt1weeks")[0].valueAsDate = now;

    $( "#dt0weeks" )
    .change(function () {
        alert('i clicked on you');   
    });
});
```

Here is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/ozrevulsion/g3nn1emw/

Answer (score 1):

check working copy on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qntp4rz7/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var now = new Date();
    //your code 


    $( "#dt0weeks" )
    .change(function () {
    alert('i clicked on you');   
    })
 });
```

and check things that are mistaken.

otherwise your code seems working for me.

note: one thing maybe mistaken is: your change function is declared before dom element is created.

Answer (score 1):

Here is it working in JQuery.

HTMl

```
<ul>
<li>
   today
</li> 
<li>
    <input type="date" id="dt0weeks">
</li>
<li>
   transfer: today + 18 weeks
</li> 
<li>
    <input type="date" id="dt18weeks">
</li>

<li>
   end date: today + 90 weeks
</li> 
<li>
    <input type="date" id="dt90weeks">
</li>

<ul>
```

JS

```
function setWeeks(id, amount){
    var tempDate = new Date();
    tempDate.setDate(tempDate.getDate() + (7 * amount));
    $('#'+id).val(tempDate);
};

setWeeks('dt0weeks', 0);
setWeeks('dt18weeks', 18);
setWeeks('dt90weeks', 19);

$( "input[id^='dt']" ).on('change', function() { alert('i clicked on you') });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/83as8bav/1/