# Failed to set the 'valueAsDate' property on 'HTMLInputElement'

Tags: jquery, html

edit: I am using this datepicker BTW:
https://github.com/CuriousSolutions/DateTimePicker

I do this on the HTML page, and it works as it should:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var now = new Date();

now = new Date();
now.addWeeks(0);
$("#dt0weeks")[0].valueAsDate = now;    

now = new Date();
now.addWeeks(18);
$("#dt18weeks")[0].valueAsDate = now;

now = new Date();
now.addWeeks(90);
$("#dt90weeks")[0].valueAsDate = now;

now = new Date();
now.addWeeks(1);
$("#dt1weeks")[0].valueAsDate = now;

});
```

And it works as it should.

However, when I try to do almost the same thing like this:

```
    $(function() {
    $("#dt0weeks").change(function () {
        alert('I changed on you');  
        //now = new Date();
        //now.addWeeks(0);
        //$("#dt0weeks")[0].valueAsDate = now;  

        var now = new Date();

        now = new Date("2019-03-25");
        now.addWeeks(18);
        $("#dt18weeks")[0].valueAsDate = now;

        now = new Date("2015-03-25");
        now.addWeeks(90);
        $("#dt90weeks")[0].valueAsDate = now;

        now = new Date("2011-03-25");
        now.addWeeks(1);
        $("#dt1weeks")[0].valueAsDate = now;    
    });
    });
```

It won't work, i get the `Failed to set the 'valueAsDate' property on 'HTMLInputElement'` error, here's an image. I don't get why.
[image]

Comment: From the [documentation](http://curioussolutions.github.io/DateTimePicker/) it appears the plugin has no `valueAsDate` property or method. What behaviour are you expecting it to have?

Comment: What I want to achieve is as follows: 1st time the page loades, to have 1st field with todays date, 2nd field  with todays date + 18 weeks. 3rd field with todays date + 90 weeks and the 4th one with todays date + 1 week. I did that and it works. However, now I want to implement it to make it dynamic, basically to be able to change the 1st field with any date and change (calculate: +18, +90, +1 weeks) the other 3 fields in function of what I picked in the 1st field.

Comment: I fixed this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31960671/populate-fields-with-dates-js-jq/32005800#32005800

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31960671/populate-fields-with-dates-js-jq/32005800#32005800