# Populate fields with dates JS/JQ

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this line:

```
<input type="date" id="Date1" name='date' data-role='datebox' 
data-options='{"dateFormat": "mm/dd/YYYY"}' />
```

Works as it should, I'm using [this](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/).
When I click on that `<input>` a datepicker will come up and and the user will be able to choose a date with the **mm/dd/yyyy** format.

However, I want to populate that field, before, let's say onload, window ready, I don't even care, with the date of today.

I'm trying this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
today = new Date();
var dateString = today.format("dd/mm/yyyy");
document.getElementById("Date1").innerHTML = dateString;
</script>
```

And I basically know where the problem is, I'm trying to add a string into a `type="date"` field; I've also tried, instead of using `.innerHTML`, .`value` but still no luck, Not sure how to do it.

Also, keep in mind that I have 3 more fields that have to be populated.

> 1: - the one that I've already pasted >> current date 2: - current
>   date +19 weeks 3: - current date +72 weeks 4: - current date +1 week

I don't mind using JQ if needed.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
document.getElementById('Date1').valueAsDate = new Date();
```

[Refer the API here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement)

Answer (score 0):

Your datepicker seems to be able to do what you want: [RFTM darn it](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/api/defaultValue/). It also seems your are not using a regular date input (inspect your date widget you'll see that it is actually a text input). My guess is that your datepicker transforms the date input in a text input when it's initialized.

Answer (score 0):

I actually fixed it with patience and readng a lot.
Here's the code.

This to populate the fields when you **open** the document:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
today = new Date();
var dateString = today.format("dd/mm/yyyy");
document.getElementById("Date1").value = dateString;

var dateString18 = new Date(+new Date + 10886400000);
dateString18 = dateString18.format("dd/mm/yyyy");
document.getElementById("Date2").value = dateString18;

var dateString90 = new Date(+new Date + 54432000000);
dateString90 = dateString90.format("dd/mm/yyyy");
document.getElementById("Date3").value = dateString90;

var dateString1 = new Date(+new Date + 604800000);
dateString1 = dateString1.format("dd/mm/yyyy");
document.getElementById("Date4").value = dateString1;
</script>
```

And this is to **calculate** the other fields **after** I change the first one:

```
    function dateChange(fecha) {
    var anyo = fecha.substring(0, 4);
    var mes = fecha.substring(5, 7);
    var dia = fecha.substring(8, 10);


    var fechaFormato = dia + "/" + mes + "/" + anyo;

document.getElementById("Date1").value = fechaFormato;

var strDate = fechaFormato;
var dateParts = strDate.split("/");
var dateBuena = new Date(dateParts[2], (dateParts[1] - 1), dateParts[0]);

var dateString18 = new Date(+dateBuena + 10886400000);
dateString18 = dateString18.format("dd/mm/yyyy");
document.getElementById("Date2").value = dateString18;  

var dateString90 = new Date(+dateBuena + 54432000000);
dateString90 = dateString90.format("dd/mm/yyyy");
document.getElementById("Date3").value = dateString90;

var dateString1 = new Date(+dateBuena + 604800000);
dateString1 = dateString1.format("dd/mm/yyyy");
document.getElementById("Date4").value = dateString1;
}
```